# how to include html file inside js file

Tags: javascript, php, html

In php I wrote this:

```
<?php include "file.php" ?>
```

Inside html file, I wrote this:

```
<script src='file.js'></script>
```

Now, I'm working with a js file.

Inside this js file, I want to include html file like this.

```
<script>
  code to include html file here 
  code to include html file here 
  code to include html file here 
  code to include html file here 
  code to include html file here 
  code to include html file here 
  code to include html file here 
</script>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try this between the script tags  `var phpFile =  <?php include "file.php" ?> ?

Comment: its inside external js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call HTML file inside an external JS file, but you can create a helper function for that.

[Following this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) you will be able to get something like this:

```
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = "filename.html";
    if (file) {
      /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}

          //elmnt.innerHTML - THIS HTML FROM YOUR FILE
        }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /*exit the function:*/
      return;
    }
  }
};
```